# Não entra na função e dá segmentation fault

Tags: c

Olá, por favor, considere a estrutura e funções dados abaixo e os tipos definidos.
Na função main, quando entra na função par ímpar da erro de segmentation fault.
Eu não estou entendendo o por quê disto. Alguém poderia me ajudar, por favor?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    typedef struct cel {
        int info;
        struct cel * prox;
    } celula;

    typedef celula * apontador;

    /*dado um apontador (lista) imprime o camp info recursivamente*/
    void imprimeRec(apontador inicio) {
        if (inicio != NULL) {
            printf("%d\n", inicio->info);
            imprimeRec(inicio->prox);
        }
    }

   /*dada uma lisata ligada, insere um no no final*/
apontador insereNoFimRec(apontador inicio, int x) {
    apontador novo;

    if (inicio == NULL) {
        novo = malloc(sizeof(celula));
        novo->info = x;
        novo->prox = NULL;
        return novo;
    }
    inicio->prox = insereNoFimRec(inicio->prox, x);

    return inicio;
}


    /*recebe um int n e retorna um apaontador para uma lista ligada*/
    apontador criaLista(int n) {
        int i = 0;
        int info;
        apontador lista = NULL;


        while (i < n) {
            printf("L[%d] = ", i);
            if (!scanf("%d", &info))
                return NULL;
            lista = insereNoFimRec(lista, info);
            i++;
        }

        return lista;
    }


    void parImpar(apontador *par, apontador *impar, apontador inicio) {
        apontador t1, t2;

        t1 = t2 = NULL;

        if ((inicio->info % 2) == 0)
            *par = t1 = inicio;
        else
            *impar = t2 = inicio;

        inicio = inicio->prox;

        while (inicio != NULL) {
            if ((inicio->info % 2) == 0) {
                t1->prox = inicio;
                t1 = t1->prox;
            }
            else {
                t2->prox = inicio;
                t2 = t2->prox;
            }
            inicio = inicio->prox;
        }
        t1 = t2 = NULL;
    }

    int main() {
        int tamanho;
        apontador lista, *par, *impar;

        par = impar = NULL;
        printf("Tamanho da lista: ");
        if (!scanf("%d", &tamanho))
            return 0;

        lista = criaLista(tamanho);
        imprimeRec(lista);

        printf("Agora, vamos separar a ultima lista em numeros pares e impares\n");

        parImpar(par, impar, lista);

        printf("Par:\n");
        imprimeRec(*par);
        printf("Impar:\n");
        imprimeRec(*impar);

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare par e impar como

```
apontador par, impar;
```

Passe o endereço para a função parImpar:

```
parImpar(&par, &impar, lista);
```

Na função parImpar() chame insereNoFimRec() para inserir na lista par ou na lista impar dependendo do valor do item.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, @josuegomes. Acontece que o exercício pede para fazer isso manipulando os ponteiros dentro da função. Acho que esqueci de mencionar esse detalhe.

Comment: Dentro da função parimpar() você vai continuar manipulando como ponteiros.